# Find directories, where files with a specific ending are missing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to display all directories, that do not contain files with a specific file ending. Therefore I tried using the following code:

```
find . -type d \! -exec test -e '{}/*.ENDING' \; -print
```

In this example I wanted to display all directories, that do not contain files with the ending `.ENDING`, but this does not work.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [List directories not containing a file](http://serverfault.com/q/235025/4276) because that question doesn't deal with wildcards.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution in three steps:

```
temeraire:tmp jenny$ find . -type f -name \*ENDING -exec dirname {} \; |sort -u > /tmp/ending.lst
temeraire:tmp jenny$ find . -type d |sort -u > /tmp/dirs.lst
temeraire:tmp jenny$ comm -3 /tmp/dirs.lst /tmp/ending.lst
```

Comment: One-liner without temporary files if using the Bash shell: `comm -3 <(find . -type f -name \*ENDING -exec dirname {} \; |sort -u) <(find . -type d |sort -u)`

Answer (score 4):

Here we go!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

for curdir,dirnames,filenames in os.walk('.'):
  if len(tuple(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.ENDING'), filenames))) == 0:
    print(curdir)
```

Or alternately (and more pythonic):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os

for curdir,dirnames,filenames in os.walk('.'):
    # Props to Cristian Cliupitu for the better python
    if not any(x.endswith('.ENDING') for x in filenames):
        print(curdir)
```

---

**Bonus DLC Content!**

The (mostly) corrected version of the find command:

```
find . -type d \! -exec bash -c 'set nullglob; test -f "{}"/*.ENDING' \; -print
```

Comment: I think the **find** solutions fails with `test: ...: binary operator expected` if there are multiple `*.ENDING` files in a directory.

Comment: `next(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.ENDING'), filenames))` could also be written using generator comprehension i.e. `next(x for x in filenames if x.endswith('.ENDING'))`.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: Truth: the find command is hacky and not really fully tested. Generator comprehension - yeah that's another nice way to do it.

Comment: I think an even nicer solution would be to use `if not any(x.endswith('.ENDING') for x in filenames)` based on the fact that any returns `False` for an empty iterable.

Answer (score 3):

The shell expands the `*`, but in your case there's no shell involved, just the **test** command executed by **find**. Hence the file whose existence is tested, is literally named `*.ENDING`.

Instead you should use something like this:

```
find . -type d \! -execdir sh -c 'test -e {}/*.ENDING' \; -print
```

This would result in **sh** expanding `*.ENDING` when **test** is executed.

Source: [find globbing on UX.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55334/find-and-globbing-and-wildcards)

Comment: Does not work. I get the following error: sh: `-c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('`. My directory names have the format 'xyz (dfdf)'. In fact its a calibre library.

Comment: When I try it, I get `sh: line 0: test: foo1/bar.ENDING: binary operator expected` for the directory containing a file with the ending `ENDING`.

Comment: This seems to work for me with plain a.ENDING filenames

Comment: I have the following test directory structure: test->test (test)->test.ending After using this code I get `sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: 'test -e test (test)/*.ending'
./test (test)`. But when I change .ending to .xyz I get the same result. This is because i have bracts as directory name, right? How can I fix that?

Comment: @bamboo I would give up with shell utilities and look for a different solution at this point.

Comment: @bamboo please see the edit, i used the wrong formating, should work now (at least it did for me with bash.)

Comment: @DennisNolte: Just a note: The shell will not expand the `*` if it is enclosed in single quotes like  in `'test -e {}/*.ENDING'`

Comment: While this answer fails, I gave it +1 for explaining why OP's globbing failed.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [Dennis Nolte's](https://serverfault.com/a/605474/4276) and [MikeyB's](https://serverfault.com/a/605511/4276) answers, I came up with this solution:

```
find . -type d                                                           \
  \! -exec bash -c 'shopt -s failglob; echo "{}"/*.ENDING >/dev/null' \; \
  -print 2>/dev/null
```

It works based on the fact that

> if the **failglob** shell option is set, and no matches are found, an error message is printed and the command is not executed.

By the way, that's why **stderr** was redirected to `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it in perl personally

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;


#this sub is called by 'find' on each file it traverses. 
sub checkdir {
    #skip non directories. 
    return unless ( -d $File::Find::name );

    #glob will return an empty array if no files math - which evaluates as 'false'
    if ( not glob ( "$File::Find::name/*.ENDING" ) ) {
        print "$File::Find::name does not contain any files that end with '.ENDING'\n";
    }
}

#kick off the search on '.' - set a directory path or list of directories to taste.
#  - you can specify multiple in a list if you so desire. 
find (  \&checkdir, "." );
```

Should do the trick (works on my very simplistic test case).

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions here but many involve using an interpreted language. @sk8asd123 's answer seems ince. Here is another one:

```
find . -iname "*ENDING" | sed 's/\(.*\/\)\(.*\)/\1/' | sort -u
```

It is kind of dirty and has different logic than the question:

1. First find the files (any expression find can understand),
2. remove the file names (part after last /), and finally
3. find unique lines with the help of sort.

but the end result is what was desired; folders containing files matching "*ENDING".

Answer (score 0):

Heres a find one-liner.

`find ./ -type d ! -regex '.*.ENDING$' -printf "%h\n" | sort -u`

**Edit**: Oops, wont work either.

Comment: It doesn't work because you're testing the names of the directories, not of the files inside them.

Comment: I've given it another try. Badly

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type d '!' -exec sh -c 'ls -1 "{}"|egrep -q "*ENDING$"' ';' -print
```

- `q` in egrep is for quiet
- With `egrep` you can swap the regex that you need
- `ls -1 "{}"` outputs the file names from the find  command